# Use font awesome icon code without importing it

Tags: css, fonts, font-awesome

I want to use the icon in font awesome like this:

```
<i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

But if I include the font awesome, for some reasons I have problems with the another font that I'm using and also the load time is slower. So I want to use only the code for actual `fa fa-user`, so I don't need to have all those imported only for one icon!

I tried to find a solution for that, but I couldn't? Is possible to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can't only include that one icon from the Font when downloading it; the entire Font must be downloaded for any of the icons to work. You can however tell the browser the [Unicode Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range) which you're wanting to use for that font.

In Font-Awesome's case, the `fa-user` icon is at [`U+F007`](http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/), so if you only want to include that icon, you only need to specify that in the `unicode-range` property:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  unicode-range: U+F007;
}
```

That said, Font Awesome is a special case in that the author operates a couple of services which allow you to customise exactly which icons get included. On GitHub they have a Wiki entry about this: [Customize Font Awesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Customize-Font-Awesome).

Answer (score 2):

You can use this simple image http://images.time2hack.com/fa-user.png instead of the include. The down side is that you probally need some more css. :)

Comment: The beauty of Font Awesome is that you can apply CSS styling to it. If OP has 30 different `fa-user` icons on their page, all styled slightly differently, are you expecting OP to have to create 30 separate images?